# Meteor crashing

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My Meteor app is crashing with the following error:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
=> Exited from signal: SIGKILL

/home/ron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Unable to allocate ArrayBuffer.
```

This is followed by a call-stack trace.

What is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried the swapspace solution?

Answer (score 4):

This error is probably caused by your operating environment. If its not able to allocate an ArrayBuffer it may be that you don't have enough RAM or some other service is blocking meteor from allocating memory.

This error may occur on the smallest DigitalOcean droplet if that's what you're using.

It's generally recommended you have 1 GB of free ram for Meteor to work properly in development mode.

Something you could use is a swapfile to increase your ram.

Answer (score 1):

Real RAM memory could be replaced with virtual memory but won't be so fast memory... in linux this SO feature is achieved using a swap partition. In windows is using a paging file. Weirdly you can emulate this feature in the linux world using [swapspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134258/dynamically-growing-swap-file-on-debian/134261) (or create a traditional [swap partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2208/79050))

```
sudo apt-get install swapspace
```

Whatever option you choose will create swap for you and it will help you to start up your meteor app!!!

Just be aware that this will be a more slower experience than real RAM but definitely will work